# How to hint type a Callable without knowing all the necessary args and kwargs?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, keyword-argument

I would like to code a wrapper that takes in arguments a function, its args and kwargs and execute them but with some kwargs precisely known while others are unknown.

Exemple:

```
def wrapper(custom_function: MyType, a: int, b: str, *args, **kwargs) -> float:
    print(a+3)
    print(b)
    return custom_function(a, b, *args, **kwargs)
```

In this exemple I want to execute any function with first argument named `a` with type `int` and second named b with type `str` but I don't care about any other argument.

With this wrapper, I would like the following type hints to succeed or fail:

```
def f1(a: int, b: str) -> float:
    ...

def f2(a: int, b: str, c: float) -> float:
    ...

def f3(a: str, b: str) -> float:
    ...

def f4(a: int, b: str, *args, **kwargs) -> float:
    ...


wrapper(f1, 1, "a")            # test 1: succeed
wrapper(f2, 1, "a", 4.6)       # test 2: succeed
wrapper(f3, 1, "a")            # test 3: fail
wrapper(f4, 1, "a", [1, 2, 3]) # test 4: succeed
```

I tried using `typing.Protocol` and `typing.ParamSpec` in the following way:

```
P = ParamSpec("P")

class MyType(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int, b: str, P):
        ....
```

but it does not work (test 1 and 2 fail)

I guess using `Callable[...]` like this would be the nearest I can get:

```
MyType = Callable[..., float]
```

but this solution does not satisfy me since the test 3 would succeed while I would like it to fail.

Is what I am looking for impossible ?

Comment: When you say you want it to fail, it is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Esp. in case 3: for `mypy` `int` is compatible with `float` (see "The numeric tower" section of [PEP-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower))

Comment: Did you mean something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=31379e0b160cef9070666c9f83782f98)?

Comment: @STerliakov this is strange it works in your mypy playground but when I copy/paste it in my local environment I get the following mistake:
`Argument 1 to "wrapper" has incompatible type "Callable[[str, str], float]"; expected "MyType[<nothing>]"`

Comment: Uhm, it's the third test call - I replaced float with str to show how it fails with inappropriate arguments. This error is expected failure. If you have any other errors, upgrade mypy in your lap environment to the latest version.

Comment: @STerliakov you are right I picked up the wrong error example. The 1st test also fails with the following error:
`Argument 1 to "wrapper" has incompatible type "Callable[[int, str], float]"; expected "MyType[<nothing>]"`

Comment: Make sure you have the latest `mypy` version (1.6.1 as of now). This [gist](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.6.1&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=0f3289e779d99b7aa50f5b39e1c9bbf3) with pinned version shows what configuration flags and `mypy` version do definitely work - playground doesn't do anything but "take the code and invoke mypy with given configuration". If it still doesn't work for you, post another question - it does not belong to comments here any longer.

Comment: I already updated mypy (I am using version 1.6.1).

I also cannot adapt your solution to create a TypedDict like I precised in my post editing

Comment: No, what you have edited into question is just impossible.

Comment: Ok thanks @STerliakov for the advice

Comment: @Paulo-99 You should remove your edit and turn it into another question. It is not related to your main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to code a wrapper that takes in arguments a function, its args and kwargs and execute them but with some kwargs precisely known while others are unknown.

This is exactly the job for [`typing.Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate). Your example is a modified version of the `typing` docs example, but instead of returning a wrapped `custom_function` with a modified signature, your example just invokes `custom_function` directly.

```py
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def wrapper(custom_function: Callable[Concatenate[int, str, P], R], a: int, b: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
    print(a+3)
    print(b)
    return custom_function(a, b, *args, **kwargs)

def f1(a: int, b: str) -> float:
    ...

def f2(a: int, b: str, c: float) -> float:
    ...

def f3(a: str, b: str) -> float:
    ...

def f4(a: int, b: str, *args, **kwargs) -> float:
    ...

wrapper(f1, 1, "a")            # OK
wrapper(f2, 1, "a", 4.6)       # OK
wrapper(f3, 1, "a")            # "int" is incompatible with "str"
wrapper(f4, 1, "a", [1, 2, 3]) # OK
```